# Slider/SeekBar not displaying correctly on Android 7.0 device (Moto G4)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, slider, seekbar

In my xamarin forms app I use [extendedsliders](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/ExtendedSlider.cs) (slider with step value) to set values for photo quality and maximum resolution. On Android 6.0 (Moto G2) and Android 6.0.1 (Moto G3) the sliders show as expected. However on Android 7.0 (Moto G4) only the thumb of the slider is drawn. (images below)

In an attempt to solve this I've made an effect and applied it to the slider, as described [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/customizing-xamarin-forms-controls-with-effects/), but this made no difference.

Has anyone run into this problem before and do you have any idea how to solve this?

The ExtendedSlider

```
settings.Children.Add(qualitySlider = new ExtendedSlider
{
    Maximum = 80,
    Minimum = 50,
    StepValue = 1,
    Rotation = 180,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 20, 0)
}, 2, 3);
qualitySlider.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve("Effects.TauwSliderEffect"));
qualitySlider.ValueChanged += OnQualitySliderValueChanged;
```

The effect

```
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Graphics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SafetyIncidentsApp.Droid;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Effects")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(TauwSliderEffect), "TauwSliderEffect")]
namespace SafetyIncidentsApp.Droid
{
    class TauwSliderEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            var seekBar = (SeekBar)Control;
            seekBar.ProgressDrawable.SetColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#FF4081").ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn));
            seekBar.Thumb.SetColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#FF4081").ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn));
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshots of the sliders in Android 6.0.1 and Android 7.0

[image: Example from Android 6.0.1]
[image: Example from Android 7.0]

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No I haven't found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seekbar will be visible if you set the layer type to Software, either in the layout file or in code by calling:

```
seekBar.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);
```

(found the solution here: https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/pull/2085)

Comment: Tested it this morning and it works. Thank you for informing me.